# Bigcommerce give error on installing newly created draft app

Tags: authentication, admin, bigcommerce, clientid

I have created a new app in Bigcommerce and just return hello world from there.
on Login to backend and go to my draft app where i click on install app it shows me error :

```
{"message":"Request returned error code: 400 and body: {\"error\":\"invalid_client\",\"error_description\":\"Unknown client ID {rbruk81rd5fq4dteoeahxl1yh7tm008}\"}"}
```

I have followed this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Do1vRfEdn70

All the steps are fine but at the end it show error.

On running `npm run build` it works fine.

Can any one find out how to resolve that issue.
[image]

Edits :
.env file

```
# Get the Client ID and Secret from the Developer Portal
    # https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/apps/quick-start#register-a-draft-app

    CLIENT_ID={rbruk81rd5fq4dteoeahxl1yh7tm008}
    CLIENT_SECRET={8d450e3542018e9f11a30bfdc5c2d09eb6cf06587fc38ee47a184f24b580fb55}

    # Test locally with ngrok
    # https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/apps/guide/development#testing-locally-with-ngrok

    AUTH_CALLBACK=https://c9e8-203-122-42-46.ngrok.io/api/auth


    # Specify the type of database
    DB_TYPE=MySQL

    # If using mysql, enter your config here
    MYSQL_HOST={localhost}
    MYSQL_DATABASE={ecommerce}
    MYSQL_USERNAME={root}
    MYSQL_PASSWORD={hestabit}
```

Comment: Hey Prits!
Have you set the environment variables properly for your app? 
The client ID/secret should be the one from your app in the devtools portal.

Comment: Another note -- When you install an app you call a bigcommerce.authorize function (if you're using node-bigcommerce), but your client ID and secret must be set when you create the bigcommerce class. If you could share a link to your repo, that could be helpful!

Comment: Hello Heather Thanks for your response 
I have updated my .env file in question and attached repo here please check https://github.com/saxenapritesh/bigcom.git

Comment: Is there any video reference to create an app in bigcommerce or any doc for ref. like steps about how to create an app.

Comment: Hey Prits, thanks for sending that over. 
This may be due to an incorrect client ID, if that is happening. That would be a place to investigate! Also,  if you didn't yet try to rename .env-sample to .env

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late on this but for whoever finds this helpful:
you have to remove the curly brackets.

e.g:

```
CLIENT_ID= ifai84ainrb85h98g539g95
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).